# Disable button when listbox is empty

Tags: c#, button, listbox

I have a listbox and I have a button. When the listbox is empty I want my button to be disabled. When my listbox isn't empty, I want my button to be enabled so I can click on it and it will run its code.

So far I have done something like this:

```
        if(lbCalls.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            btnNextCall.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnNextCall.Enabled = false;
        }
```

However, I can still click on my button even when the listbox is still empty, and it then gives me an error and I can't proceed.

How do I solve this?

Comment: @Rnft: where did you write the above code? in which event?

Answer (score 0):

you must call it on certain EventArgs, for example, call it OnLoad, ListBox.SelectedChanged, so try to make some tests.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :** you need to run the above code in your `ItemDelete` function.

**Step 1:** create a `function` to change the `Status` of the `Button` .
**Step 2:** call that `function` immediatly after removing `item` from `ListBox` .

Try This:

```
   private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbCalls.Items.Count > 0)
            lbCalls.Items.RemoveAt(lbCalls.SelectedIndex);

        ChangeButtonStatus();
    }
    void ChangeButtonStatus()
    {
        if (lbCalls.Items.Count > 0)
            btnNextCall.Enabled = true;
        else
            btnNextCall.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: I got it to work for my listbox, but now I need the method to work for this type of situation: unless I haven't selected an item from two different listboxes, I must disable my dispatch-button. So, two items from two different listboxes must be selected in order for the button to be enabled. How do I do this?